# In DynamoDB, what happens if there is a collision on a Global Secondary Index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table which I am designing where the partition key and range key will be known and unique. I am trying to design another way to query. Because the sort key of my fields on my GSI will end up being a date field that goes down to the millisecond, I don't expect many collisions, but it is possible that it could happen at some time. What is the response of DynamoDB in this case? If I run a query against the GSI, will it still show both items that collided on the range key?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can only do `query` (instead of `getItem`) on GSIs. If two items have the same partition key in the GSI, you will get both when you query that partition key.